# Can a twilight domain cleric see colors in dim light?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, vision-and-light

The description for the Eyes of night feature states:

> You can see through the deepest gloom. You have darkvision out to a
> range of 300 feet. In that radius, you can see in dim light as if it
> were bright light and in darkness as if it were dim light.

Does this mean that a twilight domain cleric can discern colors in dim light, or do the normal rules for darkvision apply here, which state you cannot discern colors in darkness?
The way I see it, a twilight cleric should be able to see colors because the feature doesn't say that you cannot see colors. Is that the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The standard rules for Darkvision apply**

The description of Darkvision says:

> Many creatures in fantasy gaming worlds, especially those that dwell Underground, have Darkvision. Within a specified range, a creature with Darkvision can see in Darkness as if the Darkness were dim light, so areas of Darkness are only lightly obscured as far as that creature is concerned. **However, the creature can’t discern color in Darkness, only Shades of Gray.**

The description for the Twilight Cleric simply says you have Darkvision and doesn't go on to modify that in any way. Darkvision doesn't allow you to discern color.

Comment: This indeed. The "as bright light" part likely refers to the game mechanics of light levels, which usually bestow a range of debuffs/disadvantages to characters relying on darkvision, which the twilight cleric does not suffer from

Comment: "Darkvision doesn't allow you to discern color"... in darkness, right? While the question is asking about dim light?

Comment: But it is the Darkvision ability that is turning the darkness into dim light and Darkvision doesn't let you discern colour.

Answer (score 7):

Or to clarify further -- the Twilight cleric has darkvision out to 300', that works exactly like anyone's darkvision (e.g. racial darkvision to 60').

With *any* of these versions of darkvision, if the ambient light level is dim, then you see as if you are in bright light, including colors, out to your range of darkvision.  If the ambient light level is normal darkness, you see as if you are in dim light, no colors -- only shades of gray, out to your range of darkvision.  If the ambient light level is magical darkness, you cannot see.